# Gulp: Minify CSS and change Filename in import path

Tags: css, task, gulp

i have two CSS files:

- example_1.css
- example_2.css

"example_2.css" is imported via a traditional CSS import statement in the "example_1.css":

```
@import url("example_2.css");
```

I had to split these files because of the "Max 4096 Selectors IE Bug"....

If i want to minify these two scripts via a Gulp task, the import path isn't updated.

So i get:

- example_1.min.css
- example_2.min.css

But the import path is still:

```
@import url("example_2.css");
```

But it should be

```
@import url("example_2.min.css");
```

Is there a solution for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out `gulp-rename` like so... `.pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can update the name. You could compile the minified files in a subfolder without renaming them and link to these files in your HTML.